# ServiceStack Swagger apis Empty

Tags: c#, mono, servicestack

I'm self hosting ServiceStack on linux with mono.  I have the Swagger feature setup but resources is returning no apis:

```
{"swaggerVersion":"1.1","basePath":"http://localhost:1337","apis":[]}
```

I have my request object annotated thusly :

```cs
[Api("My Service")]
[Route("/hello", "GET", Summary = @"Default hello service.", Notes = "Longer description for hello service.")]
[Route("/hello/{Name}", "GET", Summary = @"Default hello service.", Notes = "Longer description for hello service.")]
public class Hello {
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: 2 things I can think of checking: 1)In the swagger javascript do you have `get` listed in `supportedSubmitMethods`? 2)In Apphost do you have anything listed for the `ResourceFilterPattern` that could be filtering out the route? The defaults for both of these settings should allow your route to be displayed.

Comment: Currently I have no filters set.  This is pretty much the self-hosted example running with the ServiceStack.Api.Swagger feature added.  I stopped troubleshooting on the swagger end when I realized that localhost:1337/resources was returning an empty api list :/

Comment: Do you see the DTOs on the /metadata page and/or can you hit them? The only other reasons for it not appearing on the Swagger page that I can think of would also mean the routes were not regularly available.

Comment: Do you see your requests listed on the metadata page?